# Windy weather in Pokemon Go

Tags: pokemon-go

[image: possible indication of windy weather]
It's been fairly windy the last few days but I haven't had a "Windy" weather type show up in the weather panel.

Are the wispy white lines in my image (right hand side) an indication of wind? Or is there an actual weather panel for wind, and it just hasn't been windy enough to see it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The wispy lines do mean windy weather. All weather has an indication on the map as you can see here: 
 [image: Pokemon Go Weather Indicators]

Picture courtesy of IGN ([Wiki Page](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/pokemon-go/Weather))

Comment: Hmm seems strange that I haven't had the kite symbol to indicate it's windy but i've had the wispy lines. Any idea if I would still receive the benefits of windy weather without the kite symbol?

Comment: Hmm, I guess not. But I think it's still detecting you have windy weather.

Comment: @Supergoat21 I’ve had rain falling lightly even though the weather indicator did not show rainy weather. I suspect that there could be ‘not strong enough’ wind in the same manner.

Answer (score 1):

"Windy" weather and associated bonuses are *not* indicated by wisps on the map, but rather by the "kite" icon in the weather/bonus circle.

The proper icon can be seen in the left-most screenshot

[image]

The question's screenshot demonstrates these wisps are not the indicator, as they are present during the "partly-cloudy night" weather state (see circle in bottom right of screenshot, above "nearby Pokemon" indicator).

Comment: Please read @Jan 's comment, the fact is, the user was experiencing wind, but not a strong enough wind for the indication of a 'kite' icon.

Comment: To further clarify the accepted answer. The wispy lines mean wind but as discussed in the comments these won't provide me with the bonus, they just show it's windy on the in-game map. Since asking this question it did get windy enough to get the kite symbol and i did get the bonuses

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but the in-game representations of weather are inaccurate at best. I've had those "wisps" show up when things were completely calm, and no wisps when it was a notably windy day. As far as I'm concerned, those streaks could mean any number of things, but the original question asked about "an actual weather panel for wind", and the accepted answer says "wispy lines do mean windy weather". In the literal meaning of the question, my answer is more accurate, and in the game-environment context of the other answer, it is literally false. Those wisps *do not* mean windy weather.

Comment: There is too much vague, unclear, unsubstantiated, or downright incorrect information floating around about this game out there already. The currently accepted answer can only fuel that problematic fire.

Comment: Read your own comment, "Hmm, I guess not." I.e., this answer is not right in the given context. I done have the rep to comment on the other answer, but "I think..." would not be an acceptable response to a comment contradicting your [already uncertain] answer. The lack of certain proof is evident. The answer is wrong, and there is evidence against it, furthering the case to in-accept said answer.